# Getting rid of round brackets around superscript

Tags: biblatex, csquotes

I am using the following biblatex/biber configuration:

```
\usepackage[useprefix=true,%
            uniquename=init,%
            sorting=nyt,%
            firstinits=true,%
            seriesformat=standard,%
            idemfont=normal,%
            namefont=smallcaps,%
            firstnamefont=smallcaps,%
            idembib=true,%
            style=footnote-dw,%
            nopublisher=false,%
            autocite=footnote,%
            ibidtracker=context,%
            backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

and the following csquotes configuration:

```
\usepackage[babel,%
            german=quotes]{csquotes}
```

I am quoting with:

```
\blockquote[{\autocite[53]{Watzlawick.1993}}]{Man kann nicht \emph{nicht} kommunizieren.}.
```

The bib entry is the following:

```
@book{Watzlawick.1993,
 author = {Watzlawick, Paul and Bavelas, Janet H. and Jackson, Don D.},
 year = {1993},
 title = {Menschliche Kommunikation: Formen, St{\"o}rungen, Paradoxien},
 address = {Bern},
 edition = {8., unver{\"a}nd. Aufl., Nachdr},
 publisher = {Huber},
 isbn = {3456818858}
}
```

The result is a quote with round brackets around the superscript:

[image: Screenshot]

Can anyone tell me, how to get rid of those brackets?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Without a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) it is hard to say, but maybe `\renewcommand{\mkcitation}[1]{\space#1}` (if the spacing is off, try `\renewcommand{\mkcitation}[1]{#1}`) helps?

Comment: `\renewcommand{\mkcitation}[1]{\space#1}` did the trick! Awesome. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way the citation is typeset in `\blockquote` and friends can be controlled with `\mkcitation`, see §8.7 *Hooks for Quotations and Citations*, p. 20 of the [`csquotes` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/csquotes/csquotes.pdf). The default definition is `\newcommand{\mkcitation}[1]{\space(#1)}`, you will note the parentheses there.

So we just need to make sure `\mkcitation` does not wrap the citation into parentheses any more.

```
\renewcommand{\mkcitation}[1]{\nobreakspace#1}
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Maybe `\nobreakspace` instead of `\space`?

Comment: @egreg Maybe, ... in this case here it does not really seem to matter either way, because the space is eaten by the `\unspace` in the `\autocite` command...

Comment: Hmm: `\autocite` is executed before `\mkcitation`. So, unless there's a 10000 penalty in front of `\mkcitation`, I think `\nobreakspace` is necessary.

Comment: @egreg Those subtleties escape my knowledge, unfortunately; but I will happily take your work for it `:-)`. `\nobreakspace` seems better anyway if people start using cite commands that do not go into the footnote, I would have thought.