# Csquotes: Order of punct, cite and tpunct in blockquotes does not seem to be working

Tags: quoting, csquotes

I am trying to achieve a blockquote where the quote is ended by punctuation ("punct"), followed by the superscript ("cite") and then followed by the trailing punctuation ("tpunct") in the same line.

When using `\blockquote[{\autocite[][]{Author}}][]{Some Text}{}.` the trailing punct is always in a new line:

[image]

In the `csquotes` manual I found under §9.2 (http://mirror.unicorncloud.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/csquotes/csquotes.pdf#subsection.9.2) the following hint:

[image]

So I customized my `\mkcitation`:

```
\renewcommand{\mkcitation}[1]{\footnote{\nobreakspace#1}}                                               
\renewcommand{\mkblockquote}[4]{\singlespace\emph{#1}#2#4#3}
```

(The "`\nobreakspace`" results from this question: [Getting rid of round brackets around superscript](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261006/getting-rid-of-round-brackets-around-superscript))

The problem I am encountering now is round brackets around my footnote:

[image]

The question is, how to ged rid of those brackets or how do I get `\blockquote` and/or `\autocite` to work how they are supposed to do?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes, threshold=1]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,%
                        citestyle=authoryear-icomp,%
                        bibstyle=authoryear,%
                        dashed=false,%
                        sorting=nyvt,%
                        autocite=footnote,%
                        autopunct=true,%
                        pagetracker=true,%
                        useprefix=true,%
                        uniquename=init,%
                        firstinits=true,%
                        maxcitenames=2,%
                        ]{biblatex} 
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[bottom, hang]{footmisc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\mkcitation}[1]{\footnote{\nobreakspace#1}}
\renewcommand{\mkblockquote}[4]{\singlespace\emph{#1}#2#4#3}
\renewcommand*{\bibfootnotewrapper}[1]{\bibsentence#1\addspace}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{quote}
               {\list{}{
                        \topsep=0em
                        \partopsep=0em}%
                \item\relax}
               {\endlist}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{jobname.bib}
@book{SomeSource,
    author = {The Author},
    year = {2015},
    title = {The Title}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\blockquote[{\autocite[][]{SomeSource}}][]{Some Text}{}.
\printbibliography[]
\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot in advance everyone.

Cheers,

Grodon

Comment: Note that `\nobreakspace` in the footnote is not a good idea at all. The solution in the question you linked to worked differently and was for a different problem. In your case the parentheses didn't come from `csquotes` but from `\autocite`, which becomes `\parencite` once it detects it is in a footnote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve this in two ways, either let `\autocite` do its thing and don't force the citation into a footnote manually - it will be done for you

```
\renewcommand{\mkcitation}[1]{#1}
```

Or use `\blockcquote` with `\SetCiteCommand{\autocite}` where the citation is automatically set

```
\blockcquote{sigfridsson}{Some Text}.
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes, threshold=1]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,%
                        style=authoryear-icomp,%
                        dashed=false,%
                        sorting=nyvt,%
                        autocite=footnote,%
                        autopunct=true,%
                        pagetracker=true,%
                        useprefix=true,%
                        uniquename=init,%
                        firstinits=true,%
                        maxcitenames=2,%
                        ]{biblatex} 
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[bottom, hang]{footmisc}

\SetCiteCommand{\autocite}
\renewcommand{\mkcitation}[1]{#1}
\renewcommand{\mkblockquote}[4]{\singlespace\emph{#1}#2#4#3}

\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\blockcquote[Cf.][12]{sigfridsson}{Some Text}.

\blockquote[{\autocite[][]{sigfridsson}}][]{Some Text}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I remove the `\renewcommand{\bibfootnotewrapper}`, it used the sandard definition, I also replaced `citestyle=authoryear-icomp, bibstyle=authoryear,` by the equivalent but shorter `style=authoryear-icomp,`.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but apparently I was not clear enough in my question. When I "let `\autocite` do its thing" it works fine putting the citation in a footnote, but using the syntax `\blockquote[{\autocite[][]{sigfridsson}}][]{Some Text}{}.` it always puts the trailing punct in a new line. What I want is the cited text then the superscript and then the trailing punct.

Comment: @Grodon I thought the question was bout getting rid of the parentheses? I will admit though that the empty group messes up handling of trailing punctuation, I will change that in the MWE `\blockcquote[Cf.][12]{sigfridsson}{Frits van Oostrom, u kent hem wellicht van Maerlants Wereld, is universiteitshoogleraar aan de Universiteit Utrecht. Gespecialiseerd in de Nederlandse letterkunde van de Middeleeuwen. Dus als er iemand is die van vergeten woorden weet is hij het wel. Bovendien had hij een vader Jules van Oostrom die als lexicograaf werkzaam was bij het grote e}.` works just fine here.

Comment: @Grodon Or is your problem that `\autocite` always does the punctuation switch? If you don't like that either use `\SetCiteCommand{\footcite}` or turn it off with `autopunct=false`.

Comment: @Grodon If that doesn't work please update your post to include an actual example of what you are using and the problem you are getting + an exact explanation of what output you expect (how are they supposed to work?).

Comment: I edited my original question to make more clear, what the problem is. Also when using your revised MWE it puts the punct either in front of the superscript or in a new line. `autopunct=false` does not change that either. What apparently did help was the `\SetCiteCommand{\footcite}` and usage of `\blockcquote`.

Comment: @Grodon Mhh, `autopunct=false` + `\SetCiteCommand{\autocite}` worked just fine for me: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes, threshold=1]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp, autopunct=false, autocite=footnote]{biblatex} 

\SetCiteCommand{\autocite}
\renewcommand{\mkblockquote}[4]{\emph{#1}#2#4#3}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\blockcquote[Cf.][12]{sigfridsson}{Frits van Oostrom, u kent hem wellicht van Maerlants Wereld, is universiteitshoogleraar aan de Universiteit Utrecht}.
\end{document}`

Comment: I don't know. Maybe something else is messed up in my document. But anyway, it works now and I actually like `\blockcquote` because the command is shorter than the combination of `\blockquote` and `\autocite`. I just hope there will be no pitfalls later because of any other errors in my code ...